# Normalize columns(a, b, c) by subtracting its mean value and dividing by its standard deviation, and assign the results to three new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization

I am trying to normalize columns(a, b, c) by subtracting its mean value and dividing by its standard deviation, and assign the results to three new columns. then, I need to assign the results to three new columns called a_norm, b_norm, and c_norm, respectively.

I was thinking on using df.assign() for creating new columns, but I haven't found a way to put everything together.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

you must make example to get answer by yourself.

click following link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This time, I made a simple example.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [8, 7, 2, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 5, 1], 'c': [2, 6, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df

```
    a   b   c
0   8   1   2
1   7   3   6
2   2   5   1
3   1   1   0
```

**Code**

Step1. normalize

I performed normalization within each column.

(If you need to find the mean and standard deviation of the combined a, b, and c columns, please create example and ask again.)

```
tmp = df.sub(df.mean()).div(df.std()).add_suffix('_norm')
```

tmp:

```
    a_norm      b_norm      c_norm
0   0.996616    -0.783349   -0.095059
1   0.711868    0.261116    1.425880
2   -0.711868   1.305582    -0.475293
3   -0.996616   -0.783349   -0.855528
```

Step2. concat df & tmp

```
out = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)
```

out:

```
    a   b   c   a_norm      b_norm      c_norm
0   8   1   2   0.996616    -0.783349   -0.095059
1   7   3   6   0.711868    0.261116    1.425880
2   2   5   1   -0.711868   1.305582    -0.475293
3   1   1   0   -0.996616   -0.783349   -0.855528
```